# Does every element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ belong to an open subset on the standard topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I want to know that for any element $a \in A = \mathbb{R}^n$, there is a open subset of $A$ such that $a \in A$.

Here is my attempt, but I feel like I might be wrong:

Let $a\in A$. Thus, $a$ can be described as $(a_1, ... , a_n)$. I can define an interval $I = (a_1 - r_1, a_1 + r_1) \times ... \times (a_n-r_n, a_n+r_n)$. Because $(a_i-r_i, a_i + r_i)$ is an open interval, $I$ must be an open set. Thus, $a$ is contained in an open set.

I feel like the problem with this is that I'm not proving that $(a_i-r_i, a_i + r_i)$ open $\implies I$ open. Does this go without saying or is it non-trivial? Thanks!

Comment: minor correction: you mean $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ and not $(a_0, \ldots, a_n)$.

Comment: $\Bbb R^n$ is  open in itself.

Comment: Any point in any topological space belongs to the open set comprising the whole space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I feel like the problem with this is that I'm not proving that $(a_i-r_i, a_i + r_i)$ open $\implies I$ open. Does this go without saying or is it non-trivial? Thanks!

That depends on the definition that you use for the topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you are using a metric, then you would have to prove that.

However, given a (finite) cartesian product $X_1 \times \cdots \times X_n$ of topological spaces, the standard topology on the product is that which is generated by the following basis:
$$\mathcal{B} = \{U_1\times \cdots \times U_n \mid U_i \text{ is open in } X_i \}.$$

From this, it immediately follows that $I$ is open. (It is a basis element, in fact!)

---

Other than that, your proof is correct.

---

Of course, there is an even simpler solution to your problem as noted in the comments by [Chris Custer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/403337/chris-custer): $\mathbb{R}^n$ is itself open.

---

In fact, the above is more general: given any topological space $X$ and $x \in X$, there exists an open set $U$ in $X$ such that $x \in U$. Once again, $U = X$ suffices.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The reason I am proving this in such a roundabout way is because I want to prove that these subsets are also bounded (which I think follows from my proof). I have a quick clarification to ask: what is the distinction between the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$? Isn't the same metric being used for both (i.e. the norm)? Thanks

Comment: @iaskdumbstuff: yes, it does indeed follow from your proof. The distinction is the follows: a metric on a set $X$ is a (special) function $d:X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$. Thus, the two metrics are NOT the same! They are completely different as they have different domains. Moreover, the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not the same either because a topology on $X$ is a (special) collection of subsets of $X$. However, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ have no common (nonempty) subsets. (Of course, $n \neq 1$ in the above.)

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. So when we say "the standard topology on $X$", we mean the topology that is created using the standard Euclidean distance function for $X$? Also, if it isn't too much to ask, do you have an example in mind of a metric for which my statement would not work?

Comment: We do NOT, in general, say "the standard topology on $X$". That statement is reserved only for some known sets such as $\mathbb{R}^n$ and its subsets. Given an arbitrary set, there isn't a notion of "Euclidean distance" on it. As for your last question, I didn't really get you. Which statement are you referring to? (I can interpret this in two ways - does there exist a non-Euclidean-metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which induces the same topology as the Euclidean? The answer is "yes". Does there exist another metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which induces a different topology? The answer is again "yes".)

Comment: Right, I think I understand. But in that case, the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the topology that arises from the Euclidean distance metric? As for my other question, apologies for the ambiguity, I was asking under what metric would the statement "$(a_i-r_i, a_i + r_i)$ open $\implies I$ open" not hold? (Because you mentioned that it would have to be proved for another non-standarm metric). Once again, thank you very much for all your answers. It has helped clear up a lot of my confusion.

Comment: Yes, the standard topology is the one which arises from the Euclidean metric. However, it can also be obtained in other ways like the product topology I mentioned in my answer, along with other metrics. (The metrics are different as *functions* but same in terms of the topology they induce.)

Comment: As for your question, I'm not sure how much sense that would make. For example, if you put any metric on ℝ such that (a - r, a + r) is open and then put the corresponding product topology on ℝⁿ, then the statement is true. If you just wish to change the metric on ℝⁿ, then you might as well remove the "⇒" and simply ask if the cartesian product of open intervals is open. However, for this, I do not have a counterexample off the top of my mind. (I do have one if we take a countably infinite cartesian product instead of a finite one.)